# Mikrotik - How to open a port?

Tags: networking, router, firewall

I have recently bought a Mikrotik hAP ac^2 and I am trying to figure out how to connect to my NUC QBittorrent from "outside". This is all new to me...

My ISP has bridged its router and I connected my new Mikrotik to it and configured some basic things like WiFi.

I found my public DNS name: `XXXXXXXXcd.sn.mynetname.net`.

These are my settings:

```
/ip firewall export
# dec/26/2018 15:12:03 by RouterOS 6.43.4
# software id = EBLA-R903
#
# model = RBD52G-5HacD2HnD
# serial number = XXXXXXXXXX
/ip firewall filter
add action=accept chain=input protocol=icmp
add action=accept chain=input connection-state=established,related
add action=accept chain=forward connection-state=established,related
add action=drop chain=input in-interface=ether1
add action=drop chain=forward connection-state=invalid
add action=drop chain=forward connection-nat-state=!dstnat connection-state=new in-interface=ether1
/ip firewall nat
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat out-interface=ether1
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="QBitTorrent Web UI" dst-port=8100 in-interface=ether1 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.88.239 to-ports=8100
```

My NUC is `192.168.88.239`. When I try to connect to `XXXXXXXXXcd.sn.mynetname.net:8100` my connection is `Unable to connect`. I figured out I should be using `ether1` because I connected my bridged router to it and confirmed it by unplugging and checking the state in `Interfaces` tab of my Mikrotik...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you connecting from inside of the LAN, or from the outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you're trying to connect from inside the LAN to your public facing interface XXXXXXcd.sn.mynetname.net (which resolves to a public IP).

You simply can't. Well, you [can](https://superuser.com/questions/1047745/access-external-ip-from-inside-the-network) if your router is able to and you configure it, but this is a waste of resources, I see it more like a hack thant a feature. You should always use the private IP when connecting from inside your LAN.

What I do at home is have a private DNS server which resolves my public domain to a private IP, in your case your DNS server should resolve XXXXXXXcd.sn.mynetname.net to 192.168.88.239 (otherwise use your private IP instead of your domain)

Oh, and in case you are wondering, your configuration is OK. I can publicly connect to your port 8100 (using TPC and UDP):

```
$ nmap -sU -P0 -p8100 XXXXXXXcd.sn.mynetname.net
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-01-03 12:24 CET
Nmap scan report for XXXXXXXcd.sn.mynetname.net (188.252.X.X)
Host is up.

PORT     STATE         SERVICE
8100/udp open|filtered xprint-server

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 8.60 seconds

$ nmap -sT -P0 -p8100 XXXXXXcd.sn.mynetname.net 
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-01-03 12:24 CET
Nmap scan report for XXXXXXcd.sn.mynetname.net (188.252.X.X)
Host is up (0.057s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
8100/tcp open  xprint-server

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.63 seconds
```

NOTICE: I've edited your question and my answer to anonimize your public IP

Comment: Exactly what I was asking, thank you! And thanks for the advice, I realized it a bit late :) Firewall should do its job :)

Comment: Oh, by the way, if you feel that my answer solved your problem, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the thick icon below the arrows on top-right of the answer. Cheers :-)

Comment: There is a bounty for 2 more days, I'll wait to see if this question receives any more attention before I accept, don't worry :)

Comment: Ok, I really didn't notice that! Comming from stackoverflow, most novices do not realize they have to accept the answer, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to forward the port on the isp’s router and possibly yours. I can’t tell you the specific instructions for the isp router, but if you search ‘port forward ’ then that should give you some answers.

Comment: My ISP router is in bridge mode, so I am doubtful about that. I tried connecting via mynetname and I can see some incoming traffic on my router, but I think it is getting dropped and cannot figure out why.

Comment: It is called PORT FORWARDING on outside facing router, that points to a Internal IP and PORT to allow passthrough same as IPtables jsut via GUI usually.

Comment: ISP router is bridged as I already said...

Comment: You may need to setup a dmz between the 2 routers.